# Unity get XYZ of raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am not sure how to get the coordinates of a raycast. I have looked through the documentation and from what I gathered there is no methods that pull out the specific coordinates from a raycast. How do I go about getting the position of a raycast so other objects can move with it?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)){
    Debug.Log(hit.point)
}
```

The `hit.point` is the location where the ray hit (Vector3).

Comment: Can you feed in a hit.point directly to a vector3? I saw that too but I was unsure of how to use it exactly.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) the hit.point already is a Vector3.

Comment: Nice. That's all I needed for that. Thanks! I did not know that hit.point worked as a vector3 -- or is a vector3.

Comment: @Issayah if this answer helped you solve your issue, be sure to accept it (the little checkmark to the left of the question) and upvote it to show your appreciation. This also lets others with similar questions know that this is a helpful answer!

Comment: Oops. I thought the upvote was supposed to do that, and it didn't change because of new contributor status.